# Struts 2 use javascript in child jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, struts2

i'm trying to use bootstrap tables extension by wenzhixin. In my web app i've a parent page called Assets.jsp and other child pages with other names.
Now when i create a table in Assets.jsp there are no problems, then if i create a table in one of child pages the table appears without styles and filters, only html simple table.

Example: if i put table in Assets.jsp

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.13.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.13.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.13.1/locale/bootstrap-table-zh-CN.min.js"></script>

<table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-search="true" data-filter-control="true" data-show-export="true" class="table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="input">Firstname</th>
      <th data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="input">Lastname</th>
      <th data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="input">Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="">
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@mail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="">
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="">
      <td>Anja</td>
      <td>Ravendale</td>
      <td>a_r@test.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljv2tdq9/26/)

Else if i put table into AssetsContent.jsp, that is child of Assets.jsp and included into body page with `<s:include value="AssetsContent.jsp" />`. I get this

[Jsfiddle example2](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljv2tdq9/27/)

How can i do? Thanks.

Comment: You get what? What's the problem? What's supposed to happen? What happens? Questions need to stand on their own.

Comment: Question is simply, extension libraries aren't loaded into child jsp. Into parent jsp all works perfectly. Why it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Use Data table with extra feature:-
see example:
https://datatables.net/ 
https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html 
https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html